# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, https, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm trying to post a request to the target website using multi part form data

```py
m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={"auth":{"id":str(random.randint(0, 999991)),"sign":randoms(32)},
    "data":{"action":"login","login":"embrella","password":"steffano321","stayLogged":"False"}
    })
s = requests.Session()
s.post('targetwebsite', data=m, headers=headers['Content-Type': m.content_type], timeout=5)
```

But I always end up with

```
line 25, in <module>
    "data":{"action":"login","login":"embrella","password":"steffano321","stayLogged":"False"}
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I don't know what's causing this, I've even tried converting to JSON first then posting

```py
uuhh = {'auth':{"id":str(random.randint(0, 999991)),"sign":randoms(32)},
    "data":{"action":"login","login":"embrella","password":"steffano321","stayLogged":"False"}}
    fields = json.dumps(uuhh)
m = MultipartEncoder(fields=fields)
```

But it says `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` so I guess that is very wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are passing `auth` and `data` as a dictionaries but instead they should be strings. Change

```
    m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={"auth":{"id":str(random.randint(0, 999991)),"sign":randoms(32)},
    "data":{"action":"login","login":"embrella","password":"steffano321","stayLogged":"False"}
    })
```

to

```
    m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={"auth":'{{"id":{},"sign":{}}}'.format(random.randint(0, 999991), randoms(32)),
    "data":'{{"action":"login","login":"embrella","password":"steffano321","stayLogged":"False"}}'
    })
```

to fix your issue.

[MultipartEncoder](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/blob/207ca64c2a319a80ce482a3db93dcbc7d7301436/requests_toolbelt/multipart/encoder.py#L416) tries to run `.encode(...)` method on the values of fields.
Since you're passing a dict, it fails to encode and the error

Comment: It says ``KeyError: '"id"'``
I fixed that by doing ``{"auth":'{{}:{},"sign":{}}'.format('id', random.randint(0, 999991), randoms(32))`` but now it says ``ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string``

Comment: Updated the answer. Keyerror was because of using `.format()` on a string with unescaped curly braces

Comment: It works now thanks but now when I post 
``s.post('targetwebsite', data=m, headers=headers['Content-Type': m.content_type], timeout=5)`` it says ``TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'``

Comment: That error is because of your
`headers['Content-Type': m.content_type]`
However i am not sure what you're trying to do there

If you're trying to initiate an empty dictionary and set the content-Type you should do ```headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type}```